# Issue While Add View Model Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My view model as

```
public class StudViewModel
{
    public StudLineViewModel()
    {
        StudLine = new List<CreateReqLineViewModel>();
    }      
    public StudheaderViewModel StudHeader { get; set; }
    public List<StudLineViewModel> StudLine { get; set; }
}

public class StudheaderViewModel 
{
   public int Roll_no { get; set; }
   public DateTime? birthday_date { get; set; }
}
 public class StudLineViewModel
{
   public int Sub_Id { get; set; }
   public double marks { get; set; }
}
```

```
var MainVMObj = new StudViewModel();
var StudHeaderObj = new StudheaderViewModel (); 

StudHeaderObj.Roll_no =1;
StudHeaderObj.birthday_date =null;

MainVMObj.StudHeader = StudHeaderObj ;
MainVMObj.StudLine =null;

return Partialview("StudInfo",MainVMObj );
```

**Code in View**

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StudHeader.birthday_date ,new {  @class = "InputText", onclick = "javascript:NewCssCal (this.Id,'ddMMMyyyy','arrow','','','','future')" })
```

**expected Result** 
1. birth day assign null but it show as default date like 01-Jan-0001.

**I was debug i found issue at** 
**MainVMObj.StudHeader = StudHeaderObj** -->assign object value it make null value to default value. so birth date from null to default(01-01-001)

**Please provide the solution**

**Editors Give the Ans not edit the Post**

Comment: I was try without set null, but it only work good in Get method but not in Post Method.

Comment: I'm surprised this builds to be honest. You've declared a variable `List<StudLineViewModel> StudLine` but then in the constructor you set it to a complete different class. I have tried to recreate your issue but it seems fine on my machine